# Specify pixel data type importing raster into GRASS with r.in.gdal

Tags: gdal, grass-gis

When I import 8-bit grayscale images into GRASS with `r.in.gdal` the datatype used is float32 and is unnecessarily 4 times larger. I can specify the datatype when I export with `r.out.gdal` but I can't find a way to specify UInt8 or whatever for the import.

The `r.in.gdal` documentation states that most data types are supported, but I don't see a way to specify them:

> Most  GDAL data types are supported.  Float32 and Float64 type bands are translated as
> GRASS floating point cells (but not double precision  ...   this  could  be  added  if
> needed),  and  most  other types are translated as GRASS integer cells.  This includes
> 16bit integer data sources.  Complex (some SAR signal data  formats)  data  bands  are
> translated to two floating point cell layers (*.real and *.imaginary

EDIT:
Output of gdalinfo:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: render_gray.tif
       render_gray.tfw
Size is 33433, 46876
Origin = (-12913123.333333330228925,5621610.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (3.333333333300000,-3.333333333300000)
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=Render Date: 2023-09-25 19:00:59Z
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Compiler: g++ 9

Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-12913123.333, 5621610.000) 
Lower Left  (-12913123.333, 5465356.667) 
Upper Right (-12801680.000, 5621610.000) 
Lower Right (-12801680.000, 5465356.667) 
Center      (-12857401.667, 5543483.333) 
Band 1 Block=33433x32 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Comment: AFAIK GRASS supports only 3 raster data types: 32bit INTEGER, FLOAT32 and DOUBLE.

Comment: there are gdal options available in r.in.gdal https://grass.osgeo.org/grass83/manuals/r.in.gdal.html maybe you could pass nbits that way? https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html

Comment: What does `gdalinfo` report?

Comment: Please see edit.